# PHP PDO query issue returns as object => "queryString"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO and put my query into a try block, I prepare it, then call execute on it, next `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` on it. with that inside the row I need the text I placed the PHP in a foreach loop, with the `$tools` variable as `$obj`. I then "thought" I was calling as I put in my code the variable `$obj` with reference from mySQL of 'name', 'price', and 'code'.
an error of just spitting out the query string 
`object(PDOStatement)#2(1){["queryString"]}=>...the Sql statmement.`

```
try {
    $tools = $dbh->prepare("SELECT t.item_code as code, t.item_name as 
 name, t.retail_price as retail,
                            t.sale_price as price, t.item_pieces as 
 pieces, t.qty as quantity,
                             t.sold as sold, b.brand as brand, 
 c.category as category 
                                 FROM Tools AS t 
                                 JOIN Images AS i ON t.t_id = i.t_id
                                  JOIN Brands AS b ON t.b_id = b.b_id 
                                 JOIN Categories AS c ON t.c_id = 
c.c_id 
                                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Types as tt ON tt.t_id = t.tt_id");
    $tools->execute();
    $tools->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'unable to retrieve data';
     echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
<?php
                    foreach($tools as $obj)  {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                         <article class="card">
                            <p class="text-center">
                                Item: <?php echo $obj->name; ?><br>
                                Brand: <br>
                                Price: <?php echo $obj->price; ?><br>
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" 
value="<?php echo $obj->name; ?>">
                                    <a href="#"><?php echo $obj->code; 
 ?></a>
                                </button>
                            </p>
                         </article>
                     </div>
                     <?php }  ?>
```

code message withing web page.

```
`object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(609) "SELECT t.item_code as code, t.item_name as name, t.retail_price as retail, t.sale_price as price, t.item_pieces as pieces, t.qty as quantity, t.sold as sold, b.brand as brand, c.category as category FROM Tools AS t JOIN Images AS i ON t.t_id = i.t_id JOIN Brands AS b ON t.b_id = b.b_id JOIN Categories AS c ON t.c_id = c.c_id LEFT OUTER JOIN Types as tt ON tt.t_id = t.tt_id" }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$tools->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` is a problem. `fetchAll` fetches all the rows from the statement and returns them. If you're going to use it, you need to assign the result of that expression to another variable, like:

```
$results = $tools->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you can `foreach($results...` instead of `foreach($tools...`

---

Alternatively, you should be able to just remove the `fetchAll` expression. PDOStatement implements traversable and can be directly iterated with foreach after it's executed without explicitly using a fetch method.